# how to loop through jquery selectros

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

can any one please help me to make the following code shorter or introduce a selector to do the selecting easier:

```
<body>
<ul class="mainnav">
    <li class="active"><a id="mainInfo" href="#"></a>test</li>
    <li><a id="operations" href="#"></a>test2</li>
    <li><a id="report" href="#"></a>test3</li>
    <li><a id="special" href="#"></a>test4</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#mainInfo").click(function () {
            $(".mainnav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".mainnav").find("li").find("a#mainInfo").parent().addClass("active");
        });
        $("#operations").click(function () {
            $(".mainnav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".mainnav").find("li").find("a#operations").parent().addClass("active");
        });
        $("#report").click(function () {
            $(".mainnav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".mainnav").find("li").find("a#report").parent().addClass("active");
        });
        $("#special").click(function () {
            $(".mainnav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".mainnav").find("li").find("a#special").parent().addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.mainnav').on('click','li',function(){
  $('.mainnav > li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="mainnav">
    <li class="active"><a id="mainInfo" href="#"></a>test</li>
    <li><a id="operations" href="#"></a>test2</li>
    <li><a id="report" href="#"></a>test3</li>
    <li><a id="special" href="#"></a>test4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice answer. this is more generic answer which is way better without the need to address each id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `multiple selector` to ease up your work,

```
$("#mainInfo,#operations,#report,#special").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".mainnav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Also you need to place the text inside `<a>` tag, since we are binding event to that. With out any nodes(text node,etc.) `<a>` element wont fire any events.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a9uzLe9d/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy there is a typo in your demo's css. You've written `.active` as the selector, when it should be `.active a` or `active > a` . In any case it is a good answer i've learned from it.

Comment: @VdeVatman Yeah that can be easily spotted out by OP. That is not what OP asked for. Anyway I appreciate your concern on that. Thanks.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I just pointed it out because i was testing the JS which shoul've work without any problem, but actually it didn't work, then I figured out that it was because of the css.